# Colour of border not rendering when hover but colour of text got rendered instead

Tags: html, css

When I try to hover the image area, the colour of text gets rendered instead of the border.

How do i get the colour of the border to be rendered instead of the text colour when I hover on the image area.

just need to fill up the details that stackoverflow wants me to 
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

heres the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wVeYwv
someone help me plz

```
// CSS CODE

$primary: #e5594b;


.product {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

  .item{
        transition: color 0.25s;
        &::before,
        &::after {

          border: 2px solid transparent;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
        }

        // This covers the top & right borders (expands right, then down)
        &::before {
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
        }

        // And this the bottom & left borders (expands left, then up)
        &::after {
          bottom: 0;
          right: 0;
        }

        &:hover {
          color: $primary;
        }

        // Hover styles
        &:hover::before,
        &:hover::after {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }

        &:hover::before {
          border-top-color: $primary; // Make borders visible
          border-right-color: $primary;
          transition:
            width 0.25s ease-out, // Width expands first
            height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s; // And then height
        }

        &:hover::after {
          border-bottom-color: $primary; // Make borders visible
          border-left-color: $primary;
          transition:
            border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, // Wait for ::before to finish before showing border
            width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, // And then exanding width
            height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s; // And finally height
        }
}
//HTML

    <div class="item">
          <div class="product">
            <div class="box">
              <a class="img-prod">
                <img
                  class="img-fluid product-image"
                 <img src="https://colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/store-free-template.jpg" alt="Product Item" class="img-fluid product-image">
              </a>

              <div class="text pt-3 px-3">
                <h3>A5 Photo</h3>
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <div class="pricing">
                    <p v-if="item.discounts.length != 0" class="price">
                      <span class="mr-2 price-dc">$2</span>
                      <span class="price-sale">$3</span>
                    </p>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated you code. you have applied border to `.product` class so we have to hover that and remove hover from `.item` class.

```css
$primary: #e5594b;


.product {

   border: 1px solid black;
}

.product:hover {

   border: 1px solid red;
}


  .item{
 
  transition: color 0.25s;
  &::before,
  &::after {
    // Set border to invisible, so we don't see a 4px border on a 0x0 element before the transition starts
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
   
  // This covers the top & right borders (expands right, then down)
  &::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
   
  // And this the bottom & left borders (expands left, then up)
  &::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
   
  // Hover styles
  &:hover::before,
  &:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
   
  &:hover::before {
    border-top-color: $primary; // Make borders visible
    border-right-color: $primary;
    transition:
   width 0.25s ease-out, // Width expands first
   height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s; // And then height
  }
   
  &:hover::after {
    border-bottom-color: $primary; // Make borders visible
    border-left-color: $primary;
    transition:
   border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, // Wait for ::before to finish before showing border
   width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, // And then exanding width
   height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s; // And finally height
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
          <div class="product">
            <div class="box">
              <a class="img-prod">
                <img
                  class="img-fluid product-image"
                 <img src="https://colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/store-free-template.jpg" alt="Product Item" class="img-fluid product-image">
              </a>

              <div class="text pt-3 px-3">
                <h3>A5 Photo</h3>
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <div class="pricing">
                    <p v-if="item.discounts.length != 0" class="price">
                      <span class="mr-2 price-dc">$2</span>
                      <span class="price-sale">$3</span>
                    </p>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/giana/pen/yYBpVY/ but how do i animate it like the one in this codepen, for the "Draw" border, where the colour goes around the border

Comment: Please create a new question for that so that can helpful to all and do not mess up with this.

Comment: did you created new question for your new request?

Comment: hi! yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321045/the-animation-does-not-work-when-i-hover-around-the-border

Comment: i have add the answer too check out.