# The animation does not work when I hover around the border

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the border, the animation does not render

The original code pen link is as shown below
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GVvxqq

i need the product class css to remain

how do i add in the animation without affecting the product class?

```
    //HTML

    <template>
      <div class="item button draw">
        <b-link @click="productDetail(item.productId)">
          <div class="product">

              <a class="img-prod">
                <img
                  class="img-fluid product-image"
                  :src="item.options[0].productImages[0].imageUrl"
                  alt="Product Item"
                />
                <span v-if="item.discounts.length != 0" class="status">{{discountPercentageTag}}% OFF</span>
              </a>

              <div class="text pt-3 px-3">
                <h3>{{item.productName}}</h3>
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <div class="pricing">
                    <p v-if="item.discounts.length != 0" class="price">
                      <span class="mr-2 price-dc">${{item.price.toFixed(2)}}</span>
                      <span class="price-sale">${{discountPrice.toFixed(2)}}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p v-else class="price">
                      <span>${{item.price.toFixed(2)}}</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>


        </b-link>
      </div>
    </template>


    //CSS
    i need the product class css to remain

   .product{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    @include media-breakpoint-down(md){
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .button {
        background: none;
        border: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 1em;
        padding: 1em 2em;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
        color: #f45e61;
        font-size: inherit;
        font-weight: 700;
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .button::before, .button::after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .draw {
        transition: color 0.25s;
      }
      .draw::before, .draw::after {
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
      }
      .draw::before {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
      .draw::after {
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
      .draw:hover::before, .draw:hover::after {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .draw:hover::before {
        border-top-color: #60daaa;
        border-right-color: #60daaa;
        transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
      }
      .draw:hover::after {
        border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
        border-left-color: #60daaa;
        transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
      }



    .img-prod{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        span.status{
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: -1px;
            padding: 2px 15px;
            color: $black;
            font-weight: 300;
            background: $primary;
        }
        img{
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
            -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
            -o-transform: scale(1.0);
            transform: scale(1.0);
            @include transition(.3s);
        }
        &:hover, &:focus{
            img{
                -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
                -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
                -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
                -o-transform: scale(1.1);
                transform: scale(1.1);
            }
        }
    }

    Only the border colour is rendered but not the animation
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. something wrong with `template` tag i have removed it and worked.

```css
.button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
  color: #f45e61;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img{width:100%}
.button::before, .button::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.draw {
  transition: color 0.25s;
}
.draw::before, .draw::after {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.draw::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.draw::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.draw:hover::before, .draw:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.draw:hover::before {
  border-top-color: #60daaa;
  border-right-color: #60daaa;
  transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
.draw:hover::after {
  border-bottom-color: #60daaa;
  border-left-color: #60daaa;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
}
```

```html
  <div class="item button draw">
    <b-link @click="productDetail(item.productId)">
      <div class="product">
        <a class="img-prod">
          <img
            class="img-fluid product-image"
            :src="https://colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/store-free-template.jpg"
            alt="Product Item"
          />
          <spanclass="status">test OFF</span>
        </a>

        <div class="text pt-3 px-3">
          <h3>test</h3>
          <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="pricing">
              <p v-if="item.discounts.length != 0" class="price">
                <span class="mr-2 price-dc">$5423</span>
                <span class="price-sale">$5345</span>
              </p>
              <p v-else class="price">
                <span>$435345</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </b-link>
  </div>
```

Comment: hi it does not work, it only works if i remove my product class but i want to keep it. THanks in adv

Comment: i have updated the answer there where some issue with template tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the entire block in `<section class="buttons">` and change the outermost `<div>` to `<button>` if you want to use the CSS as-is from the codepen. I have tested this and it works as expected.

```
<template>
    <section class="buttons">
        <button class="item button draw">
            <b-link @click="productDetail(item.productId)">
                //
                // custom element content
                //
            </b-link>
        </button>
    </section>
</template>
```